# problem calculating the position using php

Tags: php

I have a function below which gets name from a site. Below is the partial code, not complete. The values are passed thru a for loop using php.

```
function funct($$name,$page)

    {
        $url="http://testserver.com/client?list=$name&page=$page";

        $ch=curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,url);
        $result=curl_exec($ch);

            $dom = new DOMDocument();
            @$dom->loadHTML($result);

            $xpath=new DOMXPath($dom);
            $elements = $xpath->evaluate("//div");
            foreach ($elements as $element)
            {
                $name  = $element->getElementsByTagName("name")->item(0)->nodeValue;
                $position=$position +1;

                echo $name.$position;
            }   
        }
```

The code works fine but when i get a name i need to add a position and for each name it will be incremented by 1 to make it contentious. But when the values for the pages are passed, for an example when i move from page 1 to page 2. the count starts again from first, next page... same problem.

How can i make it continues on every page?

Comment: do u want to get titles from a url or titles from multiple url (that have a position number in them)?

Answer (score 2):

Either make `$position` a global variable (`global $position;`) or pass it to the function: `function funct($name, $page, &$position)`. (What's with the variable variable `$$name` in your function signature?)

Answer (score 0):

Use [$_SESSION](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php). It's designed specifically to maintain state.

Comment: I think in this case session is not necessary. Moving form page 1 to 2 means in this case: calling the function with `$page=1` and `$page=2`... I guess :)

Comment: @Felix: right, but the position number is relative to the preceding page. Assumably something makes the number of elements on any page variable.  If he stores `$_SESSION['last_position']`, then `$position=$_SESSION['last_position'] +1;` Of course this means that jumping several pages still only moves 1 position.